# What is the best way to communicate between JavaScript and Actionscript 2.0 and 3.0

Tags: javascript, actionscript

What about support for major browser? IE 6+. FF 2+, Opera 9+, Safari 3+, Google Chrome?
It is good idea to use actionscript to generate graphics (interface developed in JS and standard HTML forms)? Maybe its better to use canvas? What about performance?

Answer (score 2):

I would start with the [flash.external.ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) object.

Answer (score 0):

- `ExternalInterface` is AS3 specific. For AS2, use [fscommand](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/00001177.html). I can't vouch for it though, as I haven't worked in AS2. As for AS3, I've used `ExternalInterface` successfully in FF(3+), IE(8) and Chrome. Haven't heard anything about it not working in other browsers either.
- As opposed to using Flash for the whole form? Yeah, that way the form will be accessible to users who don't have flash too.
- Given that you're targeted browsers include IE-6 et al, [Canvas](http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/cross-browser-canvas-support-speed-tests/) is hardly an option. According to the linked article, no version of IE supports canvas yet. Even FF started supporting it from FF3.
- About performance, its hard to say without knowing what you are trying to do.